# Crop a polygon to a bounding box without losing box edge

Tags: python, polygon, bounding-box, intersect

I am trying to crop polygons to a box
The function I got so far is:

```py
import numpy as np

def crop_polygon(x, y, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):
    # Create a mask to identify points inside the bounding box
    mask = (x >= xmin) & (x <= xmax) & (y >= ymin) & (y <= ymax)

    # Find the indices of points that are inside the bounding box
    inside_indices = np.where(mask)[0]

    # Extract the coordinates of the points inside the bounding box
    cropped_x = x[inside_indices]
    cropped_y = y[inside_indices]

    return cropped_x, cropped_y


x=np.array([20,50,100,200,400,500,800,850,750,600,300,150,0])
y=np.array([100,120,80,140,130,110,100,99,20,10,30,40,10])
xmin=200
xmax=700
ymin=0
ymax=200
cropped_x, cropped_y = crop_polygon(x, y, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
print("Cropped x:", cropped_x)
print("Cropped y:", cropped_y)
```

Result:

```
Cropped x: [200 400 500 600 300]
Cropped y: [140 130 110  10  30]
```

Purpose here is to cut the polygon along the x axes, as can be seen by xmin and xmax.

The problem here is, that I am losing the "edges" where the polygon intersects the bounds at x.
Ideally I would insert a point at (xmin,y) and (xmax,y) or manyfold points as this needs to work for all kinds of polygons.

Does anyone have a good solution or library for this?

Comment: you want the logical operator `and` instead of the bitwise operator `&`

Comment: See [ask]. Research more, choose a library and ask a specific question if you confront a problem with a [mre] and debugging details. Anyway, did you try [Boolean operations on Polygons](https://scikit-geometry.github.io/scikit-geometry/polygon.html#Boolean-operations-on-Polygons)?

Answer (score -1):

I found a good solution using this:
[Cannot make GeoDataFrame from Shapely Polygons: NotImplementedError: A polygon does not itself provide the array interface. Its rings do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65676484/cannot-make-geodataframe-from-shapely-polygons-notimplementederror-a-polygon-d)

thanks for reading and the responses!

Comment: Why not edit the question for the specificity? Answering like this affects SO negatively.